# Sum of elements in a vector using intervals

Tags: arrays, matlab, sum, intervals, accumarray

Let's say I have a vector named `vect = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]` and another vector named `intervals = [1 3 6 9]`. Is it possible to get another vector of partial sums of elements in `vest`, using `intervals`? I want to do something like this:

Partial sum 1 = 1 + 2 + 3 (elements from `vect(1)` to `vect(3)`)

Partial sum 2 = 4 + 5 + 6 (elements from `vect(3 + 1)` to `vect(6)`)

Partial sum 3 = 7 + 8 + 9 (elements from `vect(6 + 1)` to `vect(9)`)

So what I want to do is to obtain the sum of the first `k` elements, then the sum of another `k` elements starting from the first one not in the previous sum etc.

**Original problem:**
The original problem was like this: I receive a vector with `n` values and a value `k`. Let's do `t = max(v) / k` intervals. Now, how many values from `n` are in the interval [0, t)? What about [t, t * 2)? What about [2 * t, 3 * t)? etc. Until now, I used `accumarray(v, 1)` to find how many values of each do I have and `int = (0:max(v)/k:max(v))` to build the invervals vector, but now I have to `sum(accumarray(v, 1))` in a way to get those partial sums.

If you want to test, using this (http://pastebin.com/jCZ3qYhz : generated with `accumarray`) and `k = 16`, the partial sums have to be: 157, 167, 136, 251, 726, 1300, 1152..I'd like to be able to do this without a for/while loop :) Vectorization is the key!

**Edit:**
To get my first sum, I use this: `sum(accumarray(v, 1)(1:16))`, for the second one: `sum(accumarray(v, 1)(17:32))`, but I don't know how to vectorize this operation. I tried this: `i = (1:16:500)`. Then `sum(accumarray(v, 1)(i(1:length(i)) : i(2:length(i)))` but it's not really working or I don't use the right thing.

Comment: By the way, I have another question. I have now a big vector with decimals and as before, some limits. How can I count how many values are in each interval? Acumarray seems not to work with decimals, only positive integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first problem I would use this:

```
cs = cumsum(vect);
i2 = intervals(2:end);
result = [cs(i2(1)), diff(cs(i2))]

result =

     6    15    24
```

This will build the [cumulative sum](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) of all elements, find the ends of the parts, and then find the differences between the sums at the end of the parts (which are precisely the sums of the elements in-between).

Comment: Thanks! I adapted the code and it's working great. I did not know about the diff function. Have a nice day!

Comment: By the way, I have another question. I have now a big vector with decimals and as before, some intervals. How can I count how many values are in each interval? Acumarray seems not to work with decimals, only positive integers.

Comment: @Adi you could use `arrayfun` with `find` to find the last element of `intervals` strictly smaller than `x`, for all in `vect`, then `accumarray` to count.

Comment: Yes, strictly smaller than x, but I also want bigger than another number. It would be something like x >= intervals(k) & x < intervals(k+1). Intervals(k) it's not a whole number (always). I can't really achieve that easily...

Comment: @Adi that's why I wrote *last*... That assumes that `intervals` is ordered, of course

Comment: @Adi to get you started with an example: `intervals = 1:1.1:8; find(intervals < 5.3, 1, 'last')`